# Malware terminated in Ollydbg after a while - Why?

Tags: malware, dynamic-analysis

I try to analyze a backdoor program with ollydbg. When I go through the assembly code by clicking the "Step Over"-Button, i stop sometimes to make a notice on a paper.
Later when i want to go trough the code again, suddenly the malware terminates itself.
I dont know why but it terminates.

Could it be a anti-debugging mechanism ? Because the behaviour its not normal. 
Someone has made same experiences and can help me?

edit: I have read something about a "Timing Checks" as anti-debuging techniques used by malware. So, with that technique the malware itself is able to find out if it is debugged.
Could it be something like that ?

Comment: This is way too specific to the particular sample to give any answer. All we could give is ideas how to approach such situation.

Comment: Even after your edit, you do not give enough information to permit to answer. You should investigate deeper and give more insight of the program you are analyzing.